# Unexpected Token L when printing a json object Using advanced rest chrome

Tags: java, json, rest, servlets

Im using a servlet that connects to a database and prints out whether or not you are logged in or not, When using `printWriter.write(JsonObject)` i get the error in rest Unexpected Token L. I am using a tomcat server to host the data.

```
public class Login extends HttpServlet {
static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
   static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/employeedatabase";
   //  Database credentials
   static final String USER = "root";
   static final String PASS = "admin";
   static Connection conn = null;
   static Statement stmt = null;
   static ResultSet rs;
   static PrintWriter out;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public Login() {
    super();
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    out = response.getWriter();
    String email = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    String result = "";

    if(Validation.validateNull(email) && Validation.validateNull(password)){
    if(!Validation.validateEmail(email))
    {

        result = "Invalid email";
    }
    if(databaseFuctions.Login(email,password))
    {

        result = "Login accepted";
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
             conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            getFromDatabase("manager",email,request,response);
        //  getFromDatabase("qa",email,request,response);
        //  getFromDatabase("developer",email,request,response);
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         System.out.println(e1.getMessage());
        }

    }
    else if(!databaseFuctions.Login(email, password))
    {
        result = "Login invalid";
    }}
    else{
        result = "No login/password entered";
    }
    out.write(result);


}
public static void getFromDatabase(String table,String email,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    JSONObject JObject = new JSONObject();

    ResultSet ds;
    try {

        ds = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * from "+table+" where email = '"+email+"'");
        while(ds.next()) 
        {
            int id = ds.getInt("id");
            int salary = ds.getInt("salary");
            String name = ds.getString("name");
            String role = ds.getString("role");
            String emailAddress = ds.getString("email");
            String phone = ds.getString("phone");
            JObject.put("id", id);
            JObject.put("salary", salary);
            JObject.put("name", name);
            JObject.put("role", role);
            JObject.put("email", emailAddress);
            JObject.put("phone", phone);

        }

}
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    out.print(JObject.toString());
    out.flush();
    System.out.println(JObject.toString());
}
```

When printing in the system i get all the correct data, or checking the raw data from rest i get the correct data. But i dont quite understand why the printer is throwing the exception any help is amazing

Comment: Mutable and shared `static` fields in a `Servlet` are a big no-no.

Comment: Also, please show the full stack trace.

Comment: There is no error coming from the java side, its coming from the rest client when viewing the information, the raw data as in what java is saving is working fine, i can sysout and get the information. When actually printing i.e. the out.print thats when rest is coming up with the Unexpected token L in the json data. But the raw data is the correct information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok If the error is in the client is beacuse you are returning a mal formed JSON value, so you are returning something like that: `{ id: 13, name: "Name"}Login invalid` then the first character the L is not valid for the JSON Syntax.
This is becuase you are writing in the response the json string from the method getFromDatabase `out.print(JObject.toString());` and after the method call you add to the response the string `result = "Login invalid"; out.write(result);` that cause you have a invalid JSON.

One way to solve this is return the JSONObject from the method getFromDatabase, and add the put the result method in this object `JObject.put("result", result)` and the write the object to the response.

Comment: Thank you for the answer i now feel really stupid because that was an easy fix!

Comment: You're welcome I had a similar issue in the past it is the way we learn.