# Ionic retrieving JSON data

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework, controller

I have the following JSON and I am having issues in retrieving the data and displaying it in IONIC. Can someone provide me some guidance ?

JSON

```
mynews_JsonCallBack({
"items":[
{"headline":"Cat",
"link":"http://www.mynews.com/1",
"description":"Yellow cat",
"pubdate":"Fri, 10 Jun 2016 06:00:19",
"image":"http://www.mynews.com/1.jpg"},
{"headline":"Dog",
"link":"http://www.mynews.com/2",
"description":"Blue dog",
"pubdate":"Fri, 10 Jun 2016 06:00:19",
"image":"http://www.mynews.com/2.jpg"}
]});
```

Controller

```
.controller('NewsCtrl', function($http, $scope) {
  $scope.news = [];
  $http.get('https://www.mynews.com/.json')
    .success(function(response) {
      $scope.news.push = response.headline;
    });
})
```

Comment: If you browse to `https://www.mynews.com/.json` - do you see json?

Comment: James : If I browse to https://www.mynews.com/.json, I get the following...as per the JSON displayed above.

`mynews_JsonCallBack({
"items":[
{"headline":"Cat",
"link":"http://www.mynews.com/1",
"description":"Yellow cat",
"pubdate":"Fri, 10 Jun 2016 06:00:19",
"image":"http://www.mynews.com/1.jpg"},
{"headline":"Dog",
"link":"http://www.mynews.com/2",
"description":"Blue dog",
"pubdate":"Fri, 10 Jun 2016 06:00:19",
"image":"http://www.mynews.com/2.jpg"}
]});`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<ion list>
  <ion item ng-repeat = "title in news">
     {{title}}
  </ion item>
</ion list>
```

in your controller

```
.controller('NewsCtrl', function($http, $scope) {
 $scope.news = [];
  $http.get('https://www.mynews.com/.json')
    .success(function(response) {
      $scope.res = response.item;
        $scope.res.forEach(function(item) {
             $scope.news.push(item.headline);
         });
        console.log($scope.news);
    })
    .error(function(response){
     console.log(response);
    });

});
```

Comment: Still having token error.  Can you take a look at this JSON link ?  `http://clips.thestar.com.my/from-rss-to-json/star2-travel.json`

Comment: check my updated answer is will work you can take look on $scope.new in your logs you will have all the string provided by the JSON link

Comment: Hi Mohan...some syntax error in the code. I changed it to this and still having issues.

`.controller('NewsCtrl', function($http, $scope) {
  $http.get('http://clips.thestar.com.my/from-rss-to-json/star2-travel.json')
    .success(function(response) {
      $scope.res = response.item;
        $scope.res.forEach(function(item) {
             $scope.news.push(item.headline);
        });
        console.log($scope.news);
    });
})`

Comment: Here's the error.

ionic.bundle.js:20434 SyntaxError: Unexpected token L in JSON at position 0  at Object.parse (native)  at fromJson (http://127.0.0.1:49284/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:9892:14)

Comment: For this error you should check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20615648/unexpected-token-l-when-printing-a-json-object-using-advanced-rest-chrome and also refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143698/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token

Comment: i have updated your codepen check your controller and tell me what you are getting in controller `console.log(response)` and try to initialize your  like `var app = angular.module('stater.controller',[])` like this

Comment: http://codepen.io/Mohangopi/pen/ZOQvMN?editors=1010 check this i am not getting any error now and check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$scope.news = [];

.controller('NewsCtrl', function($http, $scope) {

  $http.get('https://www.mynews.com/.json')
    .success(function(response) {
      $scope.res = response.items[0];
            $scope.news.push($scope.res);
      })
    });
})

<ion-list>
  <ion-item ng-repeat="item in news">
  {{item.headline}}!
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$scope.news.push = response[0].headline;
```

instead of

```
$scope.news.push = response.headline;
```